# Google Photos API import all my photos

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-plus, picasa, google-photos

I've been reading more or less every StackOverflow question about Google Photos, and still I haven't figured out the answer.

I need, for my Rails app, to get the url of every single photo uploaded on Google Photos.

I can't use Picasa for a long term project, G Drive API does not find all the photos, G+ can't find all the photos

Please, help me find a solution O.o It can be Javascript-based, or curl-based, I'll translate it.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

I've found https://github.com/howdy39/google-picker-api-demo which lets me get all my photos inside an album. It's something, but I hope Google will release better Google Photos API soon. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**May 8, 2018:**
Good news! Google just have launched [Google Photo API](https://developers.google.com/photos/) on Googel I/O

You can get list of all your media, including albums. Moreover, API allows you to upload and share media. At the moment it is in Developer Preview state and has quota limit:

> During the developer preview, the quota for requests to the Google Photos Library API is 2,500 requests per project per day. Requests to access media bytes (like loading a photo or video) aren't counted against the limit.

Answer (score 7):

Refer to the accepted answer.

<s>There is currently no other/similar/better API (by Google) that interacts with Google Photos like [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/developers_guide) does.</s>

Other than the *alternatives* you've already mentioned, unfortunately, I don't think there's an API out there that has the functions that is (even remotely) similar to what you're looking for.

With all that said, questions asking for software libraries or tutorials and whatnot are considered *off-topic* here in Stack Overflow.

<sub>PS: The request for an official API by a lot of devs is expressed (*and hopefully heard by Google*) in a lot of sites for quite some time (like [this one](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11089174)). Belive me. (*sigh*) I understand the frustration.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I know it should be off-topic, but the frustration is really huge! I've found [link](https://github.com/howdy39/google-picker-api-demo) and I've found a way to get all the photos inside an album. It's a first step. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome. :) If you think this is considered good enough as the correct answer, do mark it as accepted. If not, I would highly suggest for you to post an answer yourself. On why you decided with that workaround and how you did it. It might be helpful for others in the future as well. Cheers! :)

Comment: I was really surprised, they have totally ruined the Picassa API, almost nothing works and google photos is a very primitive product

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Search` call, (https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search) with an empty search string, retrieves all media items.

I have recently built a tool to backup all my photos (https://github.com/dtylman/gitmoo-goog), following is an example in `golang` to list the entire library:

```
import "google.golang.org/api/photoslibrary/v1"`

func ListAll(svc *photoslibrary.Service) error {
    hasMore := true
    req := &photoslibrary.SearchMediaItemsRequest{PageSize: 50}
    for hasMore {
        items, err := svc.MediaItems.Search(req).Do()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        for _, m := range items.MediaItems {
            fmt.Println(m)
        }
        req.PageToken = items.NextPageToken
        if req.PageToken == "" {
            hasMore = false
        }
    }
    return nil  
}
```