# Saving a photo from mobile to GDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, photo, picasa

I want to take a photo with my mobile and save it to the Google Drive in a particular folder. I can, for example, wait my photo to be uploaded by Google's background service, and then save it with the script to Google Drive. But, unfortunately, code like

```
var albums = PicasaApp.getAlbums();
```

yields the error

> "Object PicasaApp is not defined".

Is Picasa API no more accessible?
How else can I send photos to Google Drive?

Comment: And where are you running this code? What have you tried? What has your research found?

Comment: what is `foto` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PicasaApp` is not a native Apps Script built-in - it is a library that must be installed into every script that desires to use it.

Library Code:
https://script.google.com/d/M4_STIXUlBANK7DGOzGApRljzL90iNPPq/edit?usp=drive_web

Follow the Apps Script procedures to [Install a Library](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries) and you will be able to call its methods.

Additional resources:

- [Picasa Web Albums API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/3.0/releasenotes)
- [Google Photos API import all my photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44006232/google-photos-api-import-all-my-photos)

Comment: Thanks a lot! After installing the library, code running good.